# Popen creates one additional process in venv

Tags: python, subprocess, python-venv

Popen creates one additional process in `venv` if I use sys.executable.

See the following scripts:

```py
# parent.py

import time
import os
import sys
import psutil


def print_process(proc=None, depth=0):
    if proc is None:
        proc = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print(' ' *depth + str(proc.pid))
    children = proc.children()
    for ch in children:
        if ch.pid == proc.pid:
            break
        print_process(ch, depth+2)


def startChild():
    python_executable = sys.executable
    # python_executable = 'python'      # UNCOMMENT this line

    commandLine = [python_executable, 'child.py']
    print(f'Child starter command: {commandLine}')
    app = psutil.Popen(commandLine)
    time.sleep(.1)
    child_pid = app.pid
    print(f"PARENT: Child's pid: {child_pid}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'PARENT started! PID: {os.getpid()}')
    startChild()

    print('PARENT: pid tree:')
    print_process()
    time.sleep(1)
```

```py
# child.py

import os
import time

print(f'CHILD started! PID: {os.getpid()}')
time.sleep(1)
```

Run `parent.py`:

```
(stack_venv) D:\stack>parent.py
PARENT started! PID: 18068
CHILD has started! PID: 13748                 <--- This is weird
PARENT: Child's pid: 19460                    <--- This is weird
PARENT: pid tree:
18068
  19460
    13748
```

The problem is that child and parent see child's pid different.

The followings needed to reproduce:

- Run in python3's `venv` (not in legacy `virtualenv`)
- Call child with `sys.executable`
- Use Windows (I cannot reproduce on WSL)

The followings are don't care to reproduce:

- The package of subprocess creation. You can use `win32process` or `subprocess`

I use:

- Win 10.0.19041 Build 19041
- Python 3.7.5

Comment: I don't know why, but using `venv` Python always creates two processes (on Windows). Thus, also your first (`venv`) Python interpreter is running two processes, even if you don't notice it. This is not the case when using `virtualenv`, though.

Comment: [This](https://bugs.python.org/issue38905) python's issue is the root cause

Comment: Virtual environments use a "python.exe" launcher in Windows, which sets the "_\_PYVENV_LAUNCHER_\_" environment variable. This intermediate launcher process can be a problem when the parent and/or the child need to be aware of each other, such as for manually duplicating handles from one or the other. multiprocessing works around this in a virtual environment by running `sys._base_executable` (undocumented) and setting the "_\_PYVENV_LAUNCHER_\_" environment variable to `sys.executable`. It would be useful to support this protocol in the subprocess module when executing `sys.executable`.